# How can we refresh the skype bot token

Tags: bots, skype, botframework

How can i refresh the skype bot token obtained via https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

Answer (score 1):

This token has grant_type=client_credentials so you don't need OAuth2 refresh logic for it. Just request a new token when the old one expires.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Flow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/#refresh-the-access-token). There you will find all the details around refreshing the access token.

[image: OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token]

Comment: Where can we set the redirect uri for this to work? Or are there any default URI's with which this can be done

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why you are manipulating the access token provided by Skype?

Comment: The token that we get using https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token has a lifespan of just 1 hour  I would like to extent it by using a refresh token. The oauth2 uses the Azure to get that, for which we need to get an account, create some application and set a redirect URI. Am not sure how this has to be done. All i need is to refresh the token( before it get expired) to sent  a message to skype bot

Comment: But why you ate getting a token in first place? You create the bot with bot framework, register it in the dev portal, make sure the Skype channel is enabled and then you should be able to talk with the bot from Skype without having to get a token. I think that I missing something here.

Comment: We have created the bot under https://dev.botframework.com/ and is communcating via APIs to send messages to BOT. For sending messages via API, we need accesstoken

Comment: Are u using Direct Line?

Comment: No we are not using Direct line. we use rest apis to sent message https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/chat/#rest-api.   Using azure i was able to get access token now, but with that i cant sent messages to bot via rest api.  ( oauth failer error) Do you know what scopes should i use while generating the access token to sent  messages via api  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40457666/what-scope-should-we-use-to-sent-messages-to-skye-bot

Comment: When the token expires you should just request a new one using the same approach you use for requesting the original token.

Comment: I need to refresh the token rather obtaining a new one. I can see steps here to refresh the token. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/. But am not sure what scopes has to be used  to generate an access token ( with capabilty of sending messages to bot via rest api)