# What scope should we use to sent messages to skype bot

Tags: oauth, botframework

Using https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code/, i  was able to generate access token. But when i try to sent a message to skype bot using the access token generated using scopes defined in above url, i get a "401: The provided 'OAuth' ticket failed authentication." error. What scopes should i use while i generate a code or access token to sent a message to skype bot via API (https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/skype/chat/#rest-api ) . The scope specified here under skype/chat/#authentication does not even takes me to login page to generate code .

Answer (score 0):

To generate a token you should do the HTTP call described in https://api.botframework.com/en-us/skype/chat/#authentication, i.e.

```
POST /common/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1 
Host: login.microsoftonline.com 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=<your bot msa app id>&client_secret=<your bot secret>&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
```

So the scope is 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'.

Comment: Using this token we can sent messages, but it has a short life span of 1 hr  and it cant be refreshed, as we dont have any refresh_token.  We need to generate a token which can be used to sent messages to BOT and can be refreshed for future use